# Mass transfer due to bulk and convection

Tags: diffusion

What is the difference between mass transfer due to bulk flow in diffusion which is (Na+Nb)(mole fraction) and the convective mass transfer which is found by kc(concentration difference)?

Comment: Related? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168218/25301

Comment: No sir , actually I'm confused in two terms one which is Ni=Ji + CiV where Ni=Total molar flux of species i , Ji=Diffussive flux of species i w.r.t molar average velocity(V) and CiV is the flux due to bulk motion, I read this equation in Diffusional Mass transfer ,now I know that convection is when we have some mechanical pump or something like that to bring Eddie, but then what does this CiV means?? And we have one more equation in the topic convective mass transfer that it Ni=(Kc)(concentration difference) , where Kc=mass transfer coefficient , confused in these too equations.

Comment: CiV=(Na+Nb)(mole fraction) can also be written