# Is the continuity equation valid for a diffusion current?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, diffusion, stochastic-processes

On the one hand, we have the diffusion equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}&=D \nabla^2  \rho
\end{align}
and on the other hand, we have Fick's first law:
\begin{align}
\vec J = - D \nabla \rho \, .
\end{align}
If we apply $\nabla$ to Fick's law:
\begin{align}
\nabla  \vec J = - D \nabla^2 \rho 
\end{align}
and insert this into the diffusion equation, we find
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}&=\nabla  \vec J \, .
\end{align}
If we now assume that the current $\vec J$ can be described in terms of a velocity field $\vec u$:
$$ \vec J \equiv \rho \vec u,$$
this yields exactly the continuity equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}&=D \nabla (\rho \vec u)  \, .
\end{align}
*Is there any error in the steps above? I'm somewhat puzzled by the result because the continuity equation is [typically associated](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/168221/37286) with advection and not with diffusion.*

Comment: Shouldn't your 3rd equation be applying a divergence, not a gradient?  Then the 4th equation should be a negative on the RHS making it the continuity equation (i.e., time variation of a density plus the divergence of a flux equals zero in the absence of sources or sinks).

Comment: Related: (average velocity in Fokker Planck equation) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/556859/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/559653/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/566778/226902

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indeed, Diffusion equation is essentially a continuity equation. More general Fokker-PLanck type equation (i.e. a diffusion equation with a drift term),
$$\partial_t \rho(\mathbf{r},t) = \nabla \cdot[\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})\rho(\mathbf{r},t)] + D\nabla^2\rho(\mathbf{r},t)$$
can be written as a continuity equation
$$\partial_t \rho(\mathbf{r},t) = -\nabla\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r},t),$$ 
where the current is defined as
$$\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r},t) = -\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})\rho(\mathbf{r},t) - D\nabla\rho(\mathbf{r},t).$$
Thus, converting a diffusion-like equation to a continuity equation is a qquestion of correctly defining the current.