# Drift velocity in advection-diffusion equation

Tags: diffusion, convection

The advection-diffusion equation is given by
$$\partial_{t}\rho=-\nabla\cdot\left(\rho\mathbf{v}_{drift}\right)+\nabla\cdot\left(D\nabla\rho\right)\equiv-\nabla\cdot\left(\rho\mathbf{v}_{current}\right).$$
Does this drift velocity $\mathbf{v}_{drift}$ satisfy a Newtonian equation of motion
$$m\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{v}_{drift}=\mathbf{F},$$
where $\mathbf{F}$
is all external, non-diffusion forces?

If so, then should the total time derivative in this equation be expanded using chain rule so that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{v}_{drift}=\partial_{t}\mathbf{v}_{drift}+\mathbf{v}_{drift}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{v}_{drift}$$
or
$$\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{v}_{drift}=\partial_{t}\mathbf{v}_{drift}+\mathbf{v}_{current}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{v}_{drift}?$$
Which one is correct if either?

Comment: Not duplicates but related: (average velocity in Fokker Planck equation) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/556859/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/559653/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/566778/226902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most usually ${\bf v}_{\rm drift}=- \kappa \nabla V$ as the drift has a similar origin to  the electric current in a resistive material.  Indeed, as the net current is zero in equilibrium one can use this to derive  [Einstein relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_relation_(kinetic_theory)). For example  there is Einstein's famous 1905  relation
$$
D= \frac{k_{\rm B}T}{6\pi \eta r}
$$
between the diffusion coefficient $D$ for Brownian motion  of particles of size $r$  and the viscosity $\eta$ of  the fluid in which they move. This allowed Einstein to estimate Avogadro's number.

Alternatively you could be diffusing in a general fluid flow, in which case ${\bf v}_{\rm drift}$ would obey the [Navier Stokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) equation.