# Advection-diffusion with periodic boundary conditions and tilt

Tags: statistical-mechanics, topology, differential-equations, continuum-mechanics, diffusion

**Context:** Consider the [advection-diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation) with periodic boundary conditions (PBC) over a flat square domain $L \times L$.
The scalar density $\rho $ is transported by a prescribed field $\mathbf{v}=-\nabla U$, where $U(\mathbf{x})$ is a scalar potential that has the periodicity imposed by the PBC. The density $\rho$ evolves as

$$
\partial_t \rho(\mathbf{x},t) = -\nabla \cdot [ \mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x}) \rho(\mathbf{x},t) -   \nabla \rho(\mathbf{x},t) ] = 0
$$

The *steady-state* solution is found by imposing $\partial_t \rho(\mathbf{x},t) =0$ and has the usual Gibbs form:

$$
\rho(\mathbf{x}) \,  \propto  \, e^{-U(\mathbf{x}) } 
$$

**The problem:** I am wondering how to find the *steady-state* in a slightly more general case, where

$$\mathbf{v} = -\nabla U + \mathbf{q}$$

The potential $U$ has the periodicity imposed by the PBC and $\mathbf{q} =(q_x,q_y)$ is a constant vector field (the constant \mathbf{q} defines the so-called "tilt" of the potential $U$).
Hence, the equation we have to solve is

$$
\nabla \cdot [ \, \rho(x,y) \, \mathbf{q} -  \rho(x,y) \nabla U(x,y) - \nabla \rho(x,y) \, ] = 0
$$

with the periodic conditions
$\rho(0,y) = \rho(L,y)$,
$\rho(x,0) = \rho(x,L)$,
$U(0,y) = U(L,y)$,
$U(x,0) = U(x,L)$. For simplicity, I tried to consider the case $\mathbf{q}=(q,0)$, but the problem still seems non-trivial.

**Question:** *Any idea or reference about the diffusion-advection equation in periodic boundary conditions (in particular about the steady-state)?  Which is the "Gibbs-like solution" in this case?*

**Further considerations:** I have the feeling that finding a solution is not easy because the "tilt" potential that generates the constant field $\mathbf{q}$ is $-\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{q}$. This "tilt" contribution males the total potential $U-\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{q}$ not periodic (i.e. it does not satisfy the PBC).

Moreover, define the total current in the steady-state as

$$
\mathbf{J}(x,y) = \rho(x,y) \, [\mathbf{q} -  \nabla U(x,y)] - \nabla \rho(x,y) \, ,
$$

so that we have to find the $\mathbf{J}$ such that

$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} = 0  \quad \Rightarrow \quad \mathbf{J} = R \nabla g
$$

where $R$ is a 90-degrees rotation and $g$ is an unknown scalar potential. Note that $g$ does not have to respect the PBC, but $\mathbf{J}$ does: (probably) the most general form of $g$ is

$$
g(x,y) = G(x,y) + a x + b y
$$

where  $G$ respects the PBC and $a$ and $b$ are constants. Even though this problem is more likely to be studied by physicists, I have the feeling that the problem is intimately related to the **topology of the 2D torus**, so I posted also a [similar question on math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3759470/532409).

Comment: What happens when you try a frame transformation, i.e. rewriting the problem in terms of  $x' = x - qt$?

Comment: Hi @Daniel, sorry for late reply. Yes I tried but unfortunately  it does not seem useful.

Comment: An observation: If $U$ is constant, no solution exists (unless $q = 0$ also). And I think I can show that solutions "blow up" (have energy pushed to arbitrarily high frequencies) as $\nabla U \rightarrow \mathbf{0}$, if they exist. Have you tried studying the 1D version of this problem?

Comment: Yes, the 1D version is basically the same. You end up with a formal solution $\rho(x) \propto e^{q x -U(x)}$ that cannot be periodic. Maybe I found something interesting here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167278914002449?via%3Dihub ..it seems the "correct" thing to do is to consider the adjoint version of the equation.

Comment: @ Quillo just updated my answer to finish the proof.

Comment: @Daniel : Thank you so much!

Comment: This doesn’t quite answer the question, but in case it is of interest: I wrote a paper studying systems of this type in some detail (hence my interest in Quillo and @Daniel ‘s discussion). https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.06431. Theorem 3 gives (small diffusion) asymptotic information about $\rho$ (cf. Remark 4). However the paper is more focused on approximating the flux of $\mathbf{J}$ through suitable hypersurfaces (Theorems 1, 2, 4; Prop. 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any $\rho$ which solves the equation on the whole torus must also be a solution locally on every subset. In particular, it must be solution on the (non-toroidal) open $L \times L $ square. Since solutions on the torus are a subset of the solutions on the square, the question becomes: Do there exist solutions on the square which happen to match at the boundaries?

On this square, we can define $V = U - \mathbb{x} \cdot \mathbb{q}$, and we have an ordinary advection-diffusion equation. We know there exist solutions of the form $\alpha e^{-V(\mathbb{x})}$. We also know that $U$ is periodic, so $V$ can only be periodic if $\mathbb{q} = \mathbb{0}$. However $e^{-V}$ could still be periodic if $\mathbb{q}$ is imaginary. Specifically, we have periodic solutions for $\mathbb{q} = \frac{2\pi i}{L}\mathbb{n}, \mathbb{n} \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.

For other $\mathbb{q}$, solutions proportional to $ e^{-V(\mathbb{x})} $ cannot extend to solutions on the whole torus. The remaining question: Are such solutions the whole solution space?

Now,  Matthew Kvalheim points to [Zeeman, 1988](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0951-7715/1/1/005/meta). Theorem 3 reads

> Let $U$ be a vector field on a compact manifold $X$ without boundary, and
> let $\epsilon$ > 0. Then the Fokker-Planck equation for $U$ with $\epsilon$-diffusion has
> a unique steady state, and all solutions tend to that steady state.

The torus is a compact manifold without boundary, Zeeman's $U$ is our $-\nabla V$, and we have $\epsilon = 1$, so the theorem tells us a solution $\rho$ must exist and is unique (up to an overall scalar). Unfortunately, this proof is not constructive.

In one dimension, variation of parameters gives the solution
$$\rho = C_1 e^{-V}\left(C_2 + \int_0^x e^V\right)$$
and the requirement $\rho(0) = \rho(L)$ fixes $C_2$. We can try to extend this to two dimensions as follows:
Assume $\rho$ is of the form $\alpha(x)e^{-V}$. Then the equation becomes
$$ \nabla \cdot [-\nabla V \alpha(x)e^{-V} - \nabla (\alpha(x) e^{-V})] = 0 $$
which simplifies to
$$ \nabla \cdot (\nabla\alpha(x) e^{-V}) = 0 $$
Solutions are
$$ \nabla\alpha(x) e^{-V} = \nabla \times \mathbf{\psi} $$
for $\mathbf{\psi} = \mathbf{e}_z $ and $g$ some scalar function. Then
$$ \nabla\alpha(x)  = e^V(\nabla \times \mathbf{\psi}) $$
If
$$ \nabla \times (e^V(\nabla \times \mathbf{\psi})) = 0 $$
then this has solution
$$ \alpha(x,y) = C + \left(\int_0^x -e^V g_y dx\right) + \left(\int_0^y e^V g_x dy\right) $$
The requirement of periodic boundary conditions picks out some unique $g$, $C$ up to an overall constant. We need
$$ \alpha(x,0) = \alpha(x,L)e^{-Lq_y} $$
or
$$ C + \left(\int_0^x -e^V g_y dx\right) = Ce^{-Lq_y} + \left(\int_0^x -e^V g_y dx\right)e^{-Lq_y} + \left(\int_0^L e^V g_x dy\right)e^{-Lq_y} $$
At $x = 0$ this simplifies to
$$ C =  \frac{1}{e^{Lq_y} - 1}\int_0^L e^V g_x(0,y) dy $$
It remains to find $g$.

I'm not sure that there is a nice expression for the solution in general. Some miscellaneous thoughts:

- When $U = 0$, $\rho = C$ is a solution, which corresponds to $\alpha = e^V, g = xq_y-yq_x$. This shows that $g$ may be defined only on the square, not on the torus.
- When $\nabla U \gg q$ or $q \gg \nabla U $, we can start with the nearby known solution and series expand.

Comment: Why would it be true that $\nabla \cdot \psi = 0$?

Comment: $\psi = \psi_z \mathbb{e}_z$, and because this is a 2D problem $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = 0$.

Comment: I think your conclusion $\alpha =$ const. would imply that there are no solutions on the torus since $V$ is not periodic. But this contradicts the fact that this PDE always has solutions on the torus (see e.g. Theorem 3 of "Stability of Dynamical Systems", Zeeman, 1988). So far I think I spot one error in your reasoning: on $\mathbb{R}^2$  I don't think it is true that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} = 0$ $\implies$ that $\mathbf{J}$ is the curl of something. Rather, as Quillo wrote, it implies $\mathbf{J} = R \nabla g$ for some $g$. Hence I think you should have $\nabla \alpha e^{-V} = R \nabla g$.

Comment: Wait, aren't those equivalent? 
$$R\nabla g = (-g_y, g_x)$$
while
$$\nabla \times (g \mathbb{e}_z) = (-g_y, g_x, 0) $$
(where $g$ is a scalar function and subscripts denote partial derivatives)

Comment: Regarding Zeeman, however, I agree that this seems to contradict. Right now I'm thinking about the $U = 0$ case - shouldn't $\rho = C$ then be a solution?

Comment: I found the mistake, I had lost a $\nabla \times $ in the third-to-last line.

Comment: Oh, I see now that you're right that the rotation/curl are equivalent - thanks for pointing this out. Yes, I think you're right that $\rho = C$ is a solution in the $U = 0$ case, and by Zeeman's Theorem 3 this is the unique solution up to a constant multiplier as you say.